# AWS CodeBuild error: Major version of alias '14.x' is not supported in runtime 'nodejs'

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have a confusing issue with AWS CodeBuild. I am getting the following error:

```
Major version of alias '14.x' is not supported in runtime 'nodejs'
```

When I update the buildspec to simply be "14" I get slightly more information on the error:

```
Message: Unknown runtime version named '14' of nodejs. This build image has the following versions: 10, 12
```

We have been using this CodeBuild project for a long time using 12.x and now require to update to 14.x. We have updated the buildspec as follows:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14.x

  build:
    commands:
      - "npm i"
      - "npm run build"
      - "npm run db:migrate"

artifacts:
  files:
    - "all"
    - "of"
    - "our"
    - "files"
```

Additionally, our CodeBuild is already on the latest version of the CodeBuild image. I have even re-built the CodeBuild project to make sure it is the latest and still the same issue:

`aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0`

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thankfully we have solved this now!

The issue was with the CodeBuild image:

`aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0`

As per [the available runtimes documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) it turns out we cannot use Amazon Linux 2 at all, we had to change to "Ubuntu Standard 5".

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: 6 months later and still the latest version of node on amazon linux codebuild images is 12 - a version that is now totally out of support

Comment: @Andy Are you able to run the codebuild on "Ubuntu Standard 6" now? I still seem to get the same error even after AWS saying it supports nodejs 16 in codebuild now

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you provided the actual image source you replaced it with (aws/codebuild/standard:5.0). Found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

Answer (score 18):

If you absolutely need to use Amazon Linux 2 instead of Ubuntu, you can install Node 14 using the pre-installed [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package in CodeBuild:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - n 14.18.3

  build:
    commands:
      - npm i #etc
```

In our case we needed to build dependencies to run in Lambda. Since Lambda runs a version of Amazon Linux 2, building these dependencies in Ubuntu didn't work (for complicated sub-dependency reasons).

Tried and didn't work:

- [uninstall and install node in CodeBuild](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-nodejs-on-amazon-linux/): when we ran `node --version` it still said 12
- install and manage versions with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm): ran into problems getting the `nvm` command to register

Then we realized that [n was already pre-installed in CodeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70196786/17977621) and managing the node version.

In the end, no complicated commands needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is actually really useful for the future as we'll be deploying to Lambda at some point. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution worked for me

Answer (score 4):

select the build image that supports your runtime from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html